# can't flash or enter recovery mode

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, fastboot, xiaomi

hi i got a xiaomi redmi note 3 pro and i wanted to flash the latest version of miui, so my previous build that i got was a rooted phone with twrp and i wanted to flash with otg. i did the common process y'know wipe etc.

but while it was restarting it stop at the boot logo a long time.....
and still , i can just enter fastboot mode and not the recovery..
when i'm trying to restart it or anithing like this i shows the logo again

i started my research to find a solution and tried to start recovery with adb fastboot on my pc, but my pc didn't detect my device. i searched the internbet for a suitable driver but found nothing.

and now i need help. plsssss i need your help

Answer (score 1):

You'll use fastboot mode to flash a ROM to your phone. A Windows computer is needed.

Important Note: *Make sure that your device is fully charged or has enough power for this process. This guide will help you update your device to the latest MIUI ROM version. All user data will be purged in this process. Please back up your data and think twice before proceeding.*

1. Download full ROM from the [official site](http://bigota.d.miui.com/V8.2.4.0.MHOMIDL/miui_HMNote3ProGlobal_V8.2.4.0.MHOMIDL_c50034ca06_6.0.zip)
2. Download [MIUI ROM Flashing tool](http://api.en.miui.com/url/MiFlashTool)
3. Download [drivers](http://xiaomiadvices.com/download-xiaomi-usb-drivers/) ans install them
4. Turn off the device. Press the Volume down button and the Power button at the same time to enter Fastboot mode. Then connect the device to the computer via a micro USB cable.
5. Unzip the ROM you previously downloaded. Open the file folder for the unzipped ROM pack, and copy its path on the computer.
6. Unzip the MIUI ROM flashing tool downloaded in Step 2, and double click on it to install. After installation is completed, open MiFlash.exe and paste into the address bar the ROM file folder path copied in the previous step.
   Click on the first button (circled out in yellow) to Refresh, and MiFlash should automatically recognize the device. Then click the second button (circled out in red) to flash the ROM file to the device.
7. Wait until the progress bar inside MiFlash turns fully green, which means the ROM has been successfully installed. Then your device should automatically boot to the new version.
8. Done.

Comment: i did it, also with the edl command but my pc didn't recognize my device . i was also using mi flash tool but i didn't show any device when i am clicking refresh

Comment: Install drivers already! Check USB cable or phone connector

Comment: I've added the link for drivers. Install them and try again

Comment: sry but it didn't work , windows device manmager is srtill showing a problem, code 43 unknown usb-device

Comment: Something wrong with USB connection. Change USB/port. Try in another computer. I assume that you are booted in fastboot mode?

Comment: i solve the problem , yes it was because of the port . I connected it in the usb 3.0 port .after i putted in the usb 2.0, it came up new an option came up in the device manager. Then i looked up the internet and found and forum with the same problem.  http://en.miui.com/thread-235865-1-1.html

Comment: i foolwed the instruction and now my device is ready to go

Comment: It works now? If so please accept this answer to help other with the same problem find it.